# How to set tab to 4 spaces w/out using expandtab in vi (not vim)

Tags: vi

I'm normally a vim user and now I'm forced to use vi.  Is there a way to set tabs to 4 spaces?  I'm not talking about setting tabspace=4, but actually setting a tab to equal 4 individual spaces (this is normally done in vim using expandtab).

Answer (score 0):

It may not be pretty, but `:%s/\t/    /g`, where what's between the second group of slashes is four space characters, should work.